# Moving modal to body leaves table behind

Tags: jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap for my Django project and have modals inside templatetags. I use the code below to move my modals to the document body. However, the table inside my modal-body remains where my modal was while my modal is moved to the document body. Anyone experienced this before?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document.body).append($('.modal').detach());
    });
</script>
```

Before I move the modal:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table> ... </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After I've moved the modal:

```
<table> ... </table>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nfoz9mgr/ works fine for me